# STM32F446RC Failed to be detected by ST-LINK/V2

Tags: stm32

I am currently trying to connect the ST-LINK/V2 to my custom board which is using a STM32F446RC. I am able to detect the ST-LINK using both the STM32CubeIDE or the STM32 ST-LINK utility, however this is only displaying the serial number. but it is failing to detect the target (MCU).

Additionally, here's some more information I have gathered while trying to debug it:

- BOOT0 is set to low (hardwired to GND)
- BOOT1 is set to low (hardwired to GND)
- VCAP voltage is reading at 1.14 V
- NRST voltage is high
- VCC is stable at 3.3 V
- ST-LINK is receiving a stable 3.3 V
- VDDA is stable at 3.3 V

Comment: If you have a fake ST-LINK/V2 then it won't work.

Comment: I've never had any problems with ST-LINK clones. It's unlikely that this is the problem.

Comment: You should post a schematics of your board  in order to get an answer.

Comment: Fake STM maybe? I had issue with my Chinese stm,could not upload via STlink, I had to follow a tutorial and do some changes to some files.

Comment: Probe SWD and SWCLK, does the chip respons to anything? If not, rdp level2 is active or it's a dud.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. @Marko the ST-LINk was purchased from the STM website. I will gather more information and post it under this thread.

Comment: As a matter of general information ST-Link hardware is dirt cheap. It's not monstrously expensive like JLink (which we go out of our way never to use). It's also a large part of the reason we choose ST MCUs

Answer (score 2):

Signal integrity...

I had a similar issue years ago. The schematics was fine, the programmer was working with other boards. etc.

I had the idea to probe the SWD signal. It was a mess.

The root cause? I used 10cm long individual wires to bond the STlink to my programming socket, not ideal for high-speed signal transport.

Solution: I configured my STLink SWD to program using a much lower clock frequency. And *BAM* It instantly worked like a charm.

If you can't probe the SWD data and clock lines at the chip pins, just try to reduce the programming clock speed to a ridiculously slow speed and check if that works.

Comment: Arg ! An old post bumped at the top..... I haven't seen. But the answer it still valid for others....

Answer (score 1):

Try "erasing the chip" using "st-link utility" app while pulling down the NRST pin with a 500 ohm resistor.
If this doesn't work it is very probable that you have hardware issue(sth is broken!).